# Can I restore a selection of files into One Note?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I want to restore a number of sections within my one note Notebook from a backup and leave some unchanged.
Is this just a case of copying the files or would OneNote get confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is to open it side-by-side:

1. Back-up your original OneNote notebooks *just to be sure*.
2. Rename the back-up notebook, to avoid conflicts.
3. Open the renamed back-up notebook, it should open by itself.
4. Drag the sections you need from your back-up into your original OneNote notebooks.